# How to link 'select' with different templates in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I work with KnockoutJS couple of days and I have 2 problems.

The code is here https://jsfiddle.net/z96qcutL/5/

1. How when choosing 'select' insert one of the two templates in 'Field Forms' block?

   - If 'Text 0', 'Text 1' is selected - framing template 'placeholder'.
   - If 'Text 2', 'Text 3' or 'Text 4' is selected - framing template 'fieldListQuestions'.
   - And if 'Select...' is selected - do not display anything.
2. As with the page load, initially displaying one 'Field Forms' block. And it can not be removed.

This is two templates:

```
  <script id="placeholder" type="text/html">
    <input type="text" name="placeholder" placeholder="text">
  </script>
  <script id="fieldListQuestions" type="text/html">
    <textarea name="fieldListQuestions" placeholder="textarea"></textarea>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to the `name` property of the `template` binding. Within this function, you can check the selected value to pick a template name. Here's an example:

```js
function QuestionViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  this.options = ko.observableArray([
    { value: '0', text: 'Text 1' },
    { value: '1', text: 'Text 2' },
    { value: '2', text: 'Text 3' },
    { value: '3', text: 'Text 4' },
    { value: '4', text: 'Text 5' }
  ]);
  
  this.selected = ko.observable(null);
  
  this.template = function() {
    switch (self.selected()) {
      case "0":
      case "1":
        return "template1";
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
        return "template2";
      case null:
      default:
        return "empty"
    }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new QuestionViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="
  options: options,
  value: selected,
  optionsValue: 'value',
  optionsText: 'text',
  optionsCaption: 'Select...'
"></select>

<div data-bind="template: { name: template, data: $data }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="template1">
  <div style="background: red">Template 1</div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="template2">
  <div style="background: green">Template 2</div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="empty">
  <div style="background: blue">empty</div>
</script>
```

Question 2: You can pre-fill the array of forms with a single Field instance. Within the template, you can hide the "Remove Field" button by checking the length of the parent array: `data-bind="visible: $parent.BlockWorkingFieldForm().length > 1"`